# Android Dynamic Delivery: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved ; Unresolved supertypes : android:support:v7:app:AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-module, dynamic-delivery

I am adding a new dynamic module to my existing project.
After adding a dynamic module and making the project give me Supertypes not resolved issue.
My existing project is a mixture of Kotlin and Java

[Project Settings Gradle][1]
[1]: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RxIoYOZQxNvoSP5pzg7reG4dlQywHci3

[Dynamic modules Gradle][1]
[1]: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pflGp5aWIGf_WhJ5GNruylYr9Sia9YQE

[Main App Module 1][1]
[1]:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W3p5CsdyjhA-6pTHvsKa9aVzbJ_4HElN

[Main App Module 2][1]
[1]:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ib-xlPD0bHUR5bSRmb2GkFqqSN7yq8HW

[Error Produced][1]
[1]:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j5VQMNZndD8mI_4lpczkYHLLJpIrPP6O

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Post your issues log and sample code.

Comment: I have added images of my gradle files please have a look and let me know if any solution

Comment: Got the issue fixed. Reverted all the code and started from the beginning. All started working well. But still facing an issue when starting the new modules activity is throwing an exception ClassNotFoundException